# How to clear all existing cookies in Chrome via DevTools API (or otherwise) when using headless mode

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using ChromiumHtmlToPdf library to manage Chrome as a worker process (i.e. via headless mode) for converting web pages to PDF from my C# app.

Spinning off new Chrome processes for each conversion is expensive, so I'm utilizing a pool of them in order to reuse existing ones whenever possible.

There's a problem, however... Cookies can get "inherited" from one invocation to the next, which has unwanted effects in my case.

Is there a way I can programmatically clear all existing cookies held by a Chrome process?

ChromiumHtmlToPdf communicates with Chrome via DevTools RPC API, so I thought there might be something there. But I just couldn't find it.